# Can I change the text inside an <img> tag?

Tags: javascript, html, tags

Really rookie and simple question.
I have this:

```
<img id="imagerino"> text </img>
```

Can I change "text" to something else with Javascript? I know its possible if its wrapped in a `<div>` for example but it will really ruin my code and I would like to do it this way if it's possible.
I have tried nodeValue, innerHTML, innerText etc. Nothing works.

Comment: img is a void element, see https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/syntax.html#void-elements Void elements can't have any contents (since there's no end tag, no content can be put between the start tag and the end tag).

Comment: Hmmm so..impossible right? I mean I CAN wrap it with something as long as it doesnt alter the space it takes and doesnt need extra css to figure it out since everything is really as it should be right now and in the right place. Is there any other option outside of div, span...

Comment: You could set/change the `alt` attribute of the `img` tag = the text that appears when you hover over the image.

Comment: @iAmOren Thank you but no I am looking to change the actual text. :/ I guess I'll wrap the img tags. This was always an option just not the best one.

Comment: Well, please add your code to the question: just the parts before, including, and after the `<img>`.

Comment: What I added there is pretty much all there is to it.

Comment: `</img>` is ignored and removed from the page, so the text is just a text node = might as well be a `<span>` = then you can add an `id` to it = be able to change it.

Comment: Well, you can change it by getting the next node sibling - but that's more work than just a tag with id, and if things change = you won't have to modify your code (after searching for what went wrong... :))

Comment: I actually tried span again and it worked the way i wanted it to. I dont know what happened before maybe there was another error and i assumed it was span.